# ADODB.Command, finding rows that satisfy a condition

Tags: c#, sql, database, adodb

The work is done in C#, with an Access database to connect to.
Currently, I want to retrieve the number of accounts from the table ACCOUNT_T that satisfy the user's inputted credentials (username, email, password).

The table has 3 attributes: acc_username VARCHAR(30), acc_email VARCHAR(50), and acc_password VARCHAR(30)
The table has only one entree: 'Tester', 'test@mail.com', 'TestPass'

I want to check number of rows/entrees in the database that match the user's inputted credentials (every account is unique, so assume no duplicates), and used the code shown below.

```
//Checks whether the user has entered the correct credentials
//If correct info is entered, redirect user to the Main Menu page
private void Login_Login_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Open connection
    ADODB.Connection connection = new ADODB.Connection();
    connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=main_db;Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;";
    connection.Open();

    //Create command and object
    ADODB.Command command = new ADODB.Command();
    object rowsAffected;

    //Setting up command and parameters
    command.ActiveConnection = connection;
    command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ACCOUNT_T WHERE acc_username = \'@USERNAME\' AND acc_email = \'@EMAIL\' AND acc_password = \'@PASSWORD\'";
    command.Parameters.Append(command.CreateParameter("@USERNAME", DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 200, Login_Username_TextBox.Text));
    command.Parameters.Append(command.CreateParameter("@EMAIL", DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 200, Login_Email_TextBox.Text));
    command.Parameters.Append(command.CreateParameter("@PASSWORD", DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 200, Login_Password_TextBox.Text));

    //Execute command and store into RecordSet
    ADODB.Recordset recordSet = command.Execute(out rowsAffected);
    //Output A
    MessageBox.Show(recordSet.RecordCount.ToString());
    //Output B
    MessageBox.Show(((int)rowsAffected).ToString());

    connection.Close();

    if ((int)rowsAffected == 1)
    {
        MainMenu_User_Label.Text = "Logged In As: " + Login_Username_TextBox.Text;
        SetupPanel(MainMenu_Panel);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong Credentials.", "Login Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

However, as marked above, Output A gives the value -1 for "recordSet.RecordCount.ToString()" and Output B gives 0 for "((int)rowsAffected).ToString()". The output is the same regardless of what the user input is, right or wrong. (Meaning that the same output is given whether the user's inputted data is already in the database or not)

Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: Don't put parameters in quotes.

Comment: @LarsTech Are you referring to the quotes in the CommandText string, or the parameters themselves? Like, do I make it "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ACCOUNT_T WHERE acc_username = USERNAME AND acc_email = EMAIL AND acc_password = PASSWORD"? (Not sure how to insert @ without triggering the username thing in StackOverflow, assume they're added before USERNAME, EMAIL, and PASSWORD) Tried that one, but didn't work.

Comment: It's just `... acc_username = @USERNAME AND ...`  Any reason you are using an outdated technology?  You should prefer ADO.Net.

Comment: @LarsTech I'm new to C# programming and databases overall, so didn't realize ADODB is outdated. Will look into ADO.Net then. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
private string ConnectionString {get { return "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=main_db;Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;"; } };

private void Login_Login_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sql = "
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM ACCOUNT_T 
        WHERE acc_username = ? AND acc_email =  ? AND acc_password = ?";

    int rowsAffected = 0;
    using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (var command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        // Use OleDbType enum values to match database column types and lengths.
        // I have to guess, but you can get exact values from your database.
        // Also, OleDb uses positional parameters, rather than names.
        // You have to add the parameters in the order they appear in the query string.
        command.Parameters.Add("acc_username", OleDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = Login_Username_TextBox.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("acc_email", OleDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = Login_Email_TextBox.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("acc_password", OleDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = Login_Password_TextBox.Text;

        cn.Open();
        rowsAffected = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
    } //leaving the using block will guarantee the connection is closed, even if an exception is thrown

    MessageBox.Show(rowsAffected.ToString());

    if (rowsAffected == 1)
    {
        MainMenu_User_Label.Text = "Logged In As: " + Login_Username_TextBox.Text;
        SetupPanel(MainMenu_Panel);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong Credentials.", "Login Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

While I'm here, I also need to mention this is exceptionally poor password handling. It is **NEVER** okay to store a password like this, even for a simple personal or testing app. This is one of those things that's too important to do wrong, even in learning code. The problem is people tend to re-use passwords, so a breach for your simple testing app might also provide an attacker with credentials which grant access to something far more important. **Just don't do it.**

Instead, you must create a unique salt (or nonce) value for each user. When a user sets the password, you prepend the salt to the new password. Then you create a cryptographic hash of the combined value using an algorithm like BCrypt and prepend the salt to final value again. Now you only store this altered information. *Never* store the actual password. When someone tries to login, you retrieve the stored information, extract the salt, and use the same procedure on the attempted password. Now you can *compare the hash values* rather than the raw passwords.